# Create a DataManger together with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm all new to Firebase and using it together with Swift. I'm trying to get an understanding on how to use the Firebase Database.

Usually when working with data in Swift I create a DataManager that handles all work with data/database/api so that code is isolated and not cluttered all over the app.

In a TableViewController to load the data I can later just do something like

```
self.items = DataManager.shared.getItems()
```

When following the different Firebase tutorials I've found that in all examples all data handling are made in the ViewControllers itself. [For example this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2) In a TableViewController they would have something like:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "items")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var newItems: [Item] = []

        for item in snapshot.children {
            let newItem = Item(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(newItem)
        }
        self.items = newItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Probably they are doing it this way because this is just an example and it's easier to explain. But I think this way makes the app cluttered and I rather move that stuff into a DataManager.

I've been trying to get an understanding for how to do it in a good way but I can't figure it out. How making sure the observers gets removed etc? How would you do it? Is there a good example on creating this structure? Or is this not the way Firebase works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `completion handlers` to your functions in data manager.

Like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DataManager.getItems() { items in
        // this part will be called, when data is loaded in DataManager
        self.items = items
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

`DataManager` func:

```
static func getItems(completion: @escaping (_items: [Item]) -> Void) {
     ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
         var newItems: [Item] = []

         for item in snapshot.children {
             let newItem = Item(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
             newItems.append(newItem)
         }

         completions(newItems)
    })
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Great! Thanks! But when can I then call ref.removeObserverWithHandle(handle) to make sure the listener is removed? Also will the ref be in the DataManager and will it be used by several viewcontrollers?

Comment: @Martin I've never done this. But I'm pretty sure, that you can remove observer in data manager. And all should be fine. :) also if it helped mark it as answer pls

Comment: thanks! But when should I init the ref and when should I remove it? As the ref is in the DataManager now it could be used by several places in the app at the same time?

Comment: @Martin it depends on your class/struct. My suggestion is to use static struct for it.

Comment: Ok and in this case when do you init the ref and when do you remove the listener?

Comment: @Martin I have few models (data managers) for each main nodes. Like Post, User, etc in my project. And in all models I have static let refToPostNode = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "maindatabase/Posts") or similar. Remove listener I think you should do when you end your work with it. Something like this